# pip install a project without copying the entire project folder

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

When I run `pip install .` on a project I'm working on, the entire project folder is copied to a temporary folder before pip starts the installation process. For me, this is a problem, because my project folder contains gigabytes of data that won't fit on my disk a second time. Therefore, pip install will fill up my disk and then crash when it runs out of free space.

This is not a problem when I run `python setup.py install`, because I clearly defined which folders should be part of my module and of course all that data is not included. Also, all that data is excluded in `.gitignore`, `.dockerignore` and whatnot. However, pip doesn't care about that, as the [documentation states](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#local-project-installs):

> During regular installation, pip will copy the entire project directory to a temporary location and install from there. The exception is that pip will exclude .tox and .nox directories present in the top level of the project from being copied.

How can I prevent pip from copying my entire project folder and make it respect the contents of my carefully written setup.py file?

---

Background: I used to be happy with `setup.py install`, but recently I wanted to try git [`pre-commit`](https://pre-commit.com/), which internally calls `pip install .` to build the project. I didn't use pip as a build tool for my projects so far, but I thought this might be a good opportunity to at least make my project compatible with pip, but so far to no avail...

Comment: I have very little experience with pip, but I heard you can specify TMPDIR=/my/project --cache-dir=/my/project and --build /my/project all to the same directory along with pip install command.

Comment: Why does the project contain gigabytes of data? Shouldn't the data location be specified in config, not baked into the package? If the package is going to be gigabytes big, what's the point in installing it? Just run it from the directory as it's too big to reasonably deploy anywhere.

Comment: @hellork even if that works, that would still cause other tools like `pre-commit` to just run `pip install .`, which still copies everything

Comment: @blueteeth please read the question: I specifically mentioned, that all these files are excluded in `.gitignore` and that `setup.py` only references my source files, not data. I could add some configuration that allows me to use a different paths, but this would add more complexity and I think it's good practice to have your data close to your code. And really, the problem here is pip not respecting the config in `setup.py` instead of me having the "wrong" project structure.

Comment: It seems the documentation already specifies that functionality as you've found. Trying to circumnavigate it is going to create more trouble later down the line when `pip install .` is run by a tool you can't control. My solution is a solution.

Comment: In my project folder, there is a ton of files that don't belong into the whl generated by pip install: the .git folder, the build folder, all .pyc files, all my test code & test data, my virtualenv folder... all that stuff will be copied every time I run `pip install .` - even when I move my data folder to a different location, this is a waste of time and resources.

Comment: `pre-commit` doesn't invoke `pip install .`, and why should it.

Comment: @hoefling except that [it does](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/fa8d02281373ec18c8463515c997291b6814e406/pre_commit/languages/python.py#L195). Do your research please.

Comment: Except that this line installs `pre-commit` hooks and not your repo. Do a _research_ and not just a grep in the source code.

Comment: I would concur with @blueteeth. Seems strange to want to have so much data lying around in the project directory, especially if it doesn't actually belong to the project. It would seem like a better idea to move it to some cache, user config, or user data directory. Yes, _pip_ could be improved (obviously, no secret there), but it could never possibly cover all use cases. And yes, I would argue there is something _wrong_ with the project structure (or at least its code), since no it's not good practice in my opinion to keep the data close the the code (or at least not this kind of data).

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a long standing issue in pip, with discussions since at least 2014 (see [issue #2195](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2195)).

There were a few proposals to solve this, like adding support for [pipignore](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4900) files that work like gitignore, but so far the only thing that was implemented is adding a hardcoded rule to [ignore .tox and .nox folders](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/6770), which sure solves the specific issues that these tools have, but not the problem in general.

A workaround is to create a [source distribution](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html) (sdist) first and then to pip install that source package:

```
python setup.py sdist
pip install dist/<name>.tar.gz
```

Of course, this will not solve the issue with third party tools that call `pip install .` themselves. It has been discussed to make this the default behaviour of pip, but for reasons that are beyond me to understand this hasn't been touched in the last 6 years, so I don't expect a solution to this issue in the near future.